# Get the Value of duplicate entries in a mysql database and count them

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have a mysql database that collects application forms. Each application form gets copied into the DB.

Example :

```
ID  l  Username      
01     MW001    
02     MW002    
03     MW001    
04     MW001
```

I want to get the value of the duplicates in a number by using a session as they login to there account a session gets created where i currently show them all there details , example

MW001 has 3 applications
If i could get the full query and how to display it, this is what i used.

```
$sql = "SELECT affID, COUNT(*) FROM taffiliate WHERE affID = '" . $_SESSION['affID'] . "'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo  $row['affID'] ;
```

In short i just want to show them they applied 3 times.

Comment: add a group by username

Comment: Ok So this is the query i tried and it is now working  $sql = "SELECT affID, COUNT(*) as c FROM taffiliate WHERE affID = '" . $_SESSION['affID'] . "'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo  $row['c'] ;

Comment: $sql = "SELECT affID, COUNT(*) as c FROM taffiliate WHERE affID = '" . $_SESSION['affID'] . "'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo  $row['c'] ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is fine, you just need to give an alias to that `COUNT(*)`

```
SELECT affID, COUNT(*) as c FROM taffiliate...
```

Then you can get that value with

```
echo $row['c'];
```

And since you already have the `affID` and your WHERE clause is restricted to only that, you don't need MySQL to return the `affID`. Your query can even be

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) as c FROM taffiliate WHERE affID=123    //
```

Also, you can execute your query in many better ways after reading this

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)